How to upload a csv to aws opensearch?
I ran into this https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch-csv, via this plugin one can directly upload a csv and index it in elastic search. is there something similar for aws opensearch? I realize there is a python package - opensearchpy.
that can upload in bulk. other than this , can one directly push/upload a csv file?
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch

client = OpenSearch(...)

docs = '''
{"index": {"_index": "index-2022-06-08", "_id": "1"}}
{"name": "foo"} 
{"index": {"_index": "index-2022-06-09", "_id": "2"}}
{"name": "bar"}
{"index": {"_index": "index-2022-06-10", "_id": "3"}}
{"name": "baz"}
'''

response = client.bulk(docs)
if response["errors"]:
    print(f"There were errors!")
else:
    print(f"Bulk-inserted {len(response['items'])} items.")


There isn't an official package or plugin like Elastic Search for OpenSearch that allows you to upload a CSV file directly to AWS OpenSearch (formerly Amazon Elasticsearch) and index its contents.

thanks. are there any python client , which abstracts anything for bulk posting?

@tisha Yes, I believe you could use the bulk-es Python Package as another utility that simplifies bulk operations for ElasticSearch (and OpenSearch by extension). It can read a CSV or JSON file and push the data into an OpenSearch instance. This package wraps around the elastic search-py client and provides simple command-line utilities for bulk data ingestion.

@tisha Another option would be AWS Data Wrangler, a Python library built by AWS to handle data frames, CSVs, and SQL interactions with AWS services. You can use it to upload CSV data to OpenSearch. It will help simplify operations like CSV ingestion into AWS services.
